# Jersey 2 + Grizzly 2 + Apache Felix + Debry

Tags: osgi

How would you rate this solution?

To get all of that working on the Apache Felix OSGi, giving you a lightweight but super power full OSGi solution.

Install the Felix HTTP API and BASE
Then copy the grizzly-httpservice-bundle-2.3.22.jar to your bundle directory.

(And then full web console if you want to test that first)

Start all the services and make sure your web console works.

What you do is:

*Copy all the libs from the Jersy 2 RI directories to your felix bundle dir (the ones that list as files with not real description can be removed) and copy the derby.jar also to that directory.*

Here is my working Felix bundle directory:

> aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b31.jar asm-debug-all-5.0.4.jar derby.jar
>   grizzly-httpservice-bundle-2.3.22.jar hk2-api-2.4.0-b31.jar
>   hk2-locator-2.4.0-b31.jar hk2-utils-2.4.0-b31.jar
>   javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
>   javax.inject-2.4.0-b31.jar javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
>   javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar jersey-client.jar jersey-common.jar
>   jersey-container-servlet-core.jar jersey-container-servlet.jar
>   jersey-guava-2.21.jar jersey-media-jaxb.jar jersey-server.jar
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.command-0.14.0.jar
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime-0.16.2.jar
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.shell-0.10.0.jar
>   org.apache.felix.http.api-3.0.0.jar
>   org.apache.felix.http.base-3.0.0.jar org.apache.felix.log-1.0.1.jar
>   org.apache.felix.webconsole-4.2.10-all.jar
>   osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar

Create a basic OSGi bundle...

The plain activator override methods looks like this .. (error checking not included :) to make things a bit more clear ... but should be added)

```
@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

ServiceReference refHttpService = 
    context.getServiceReference(HttpService.class.getName());

HttpService httpService = (HttpService) context.getService(refHttpService);

ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(CHelloResource.class);

ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(rc);

httpService.registerServlet(
    "/j",
    servletContainer,
    null,
    httpService.createDefaultHttpContext());
}



@Override
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

ServiceReference refHttpService = 
    context.getServiceReference(HttpService.class.getName());

HttpService httpService = (HttpService) context.getService(refHttpService);

httpService.unregister("/j");
}
```

:)

Allot more simple that expected? To join up JAX-RS and OSGi ?

Comment: I doubt this "question" will be answered on SO.

Comment: [......   ;-)   ........ ]

Comment: What do you expect from the community as an answer? This is not a technical question. It would be more appropriate to publish something like this as a tutorial in your blog.

Comment: Any feedback always welcome. I think it's more aimed at OSGi users. Sometimes people have better ways of doing things. This was my way. It would be great is someone could rate on it. Was the implementation good or bad ? And why. The question in itself is a solution. But there are many ways to solve things.

Comment: Where's the question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error I found in your code is that you use getService but not ungetService.

Other than that you might want to use a framework so you do not have to fiddle with low level OSGi api. You should look into Declarative Services and Blueprint.

Another thing is that your approach to provide rest is very lightweight but also very limited. For example how would you do logging or security. So Apache CXF might be a good choice as it provides a lot of additional features.

It also might be quite troublesome to search for the necessary bundles to install by hand. For this you might want to look into Apache Karaf which provides a lot of infrastructure like http and rest support in easy to install features. It is a little less light weight than pure felix but much easier to start with. [See some tutorials here](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials).

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback Christian! It's the true that Apache CXF/Karaf does already do all of this. But I loved the idea of some kind of micro footprint OSGi skeleton thing. Reason being is....I was thinking along the lines of using this kind of configuration on low memory environments. Even if it's a raspberry pi. or a service on a penny vm somewhere. The security aspect of REST has always puzzled me for various reasons. But let me look at the logging and security. Very interesting indeed! PS: I like playing with low level API's :)

Comment: I am also looking for a more lightweight approach. One thing that might be interesting here is karaf profiles (new in karaf 4). It allows to build a fixed application that then for example does not need to have the shell or the feature service.

Comment: I looked into this some more and I'm going to stick to Apache Felix, security and all that is not such a big issue. PS: Check out the UPNP support it's super awesome! Super small and just what I was looking for :)